# Any better approach rather than result.getString() while iterating a result set in java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have 6 columns in a table. I have a select query which selects some records from the table. While iterating over the result set, im using the following logic to extract the values in the columns:

```
Statement select = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = select.executeQuery
        ("SELECT * FROM D724933.ECOCHECKS WHERE ECO = '"+localeco+"' AND CHK_TOOL = '"+checknames[i]+"'");
         while(result.next()) { // process results one row at a time
           String eco = result.getString(1);
           mapp2.put("ECO", eco);
           String chktool = result.getString(2);
           mapp2.put("CHECK_TOOL", chktool);
           String lastchktime = result.getString(3);
           mapp2.put("LAST_CHECK_TIME", lastchktime);
           String status = result.getString(4);
           mapp2.put("STATUS", status);
           String statcmts = result.getString(5);
           mapp2.put("STATUS_COMMENTS", statcmts);
           String details = result.getString(6);
           mapp2.put("DETAILS_FILE", details);
         }
```

I have 2 questions here: 
1. Is there any better approach rather than using result.getString()??? 
2. Lets say, another column gets added to the table at a later point. Is there any way my code handles this new addition without making change to the code at that point of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ResultSetMetaData` to determine the number and names of the columns in your `ResultSet` and deal with it this way.  Note however that changing the number of columns in the database - affecting your code - and having the code still work may not always be a good idea.

Additionally, note that you're overwriting the values in your map on each iteration of the loop.  You probably want to add those maps to some sort of List?

Finally, you need to make sure that your `getString` methods will not return `null` anywhere, otherwise putting it into a map will throw an exception.

```
Statement select = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM D724933.ECOCHECKS WHERE ECO = '"+localeco+"' AND CHK_TOOL = '"+checknames[i]+"'");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();

int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();    
List data = new ArrayList<Map>();
Map mapp2;

while(result.next()) { // process results one row at a time
    mapp2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=numberOfColumns; i++) {
        mapp2.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), rs.getString(i));
    }
    data.add(mapp2);
}
```

Comment: @jtahlborn Because I am retrieving all columns and retrieving by index is faster than retrieving by name.  If you feel like it, you can use `rs.getString(rsmd.getColumnName(i))` - but why?  Remember, the column names are not available in advance, I need to get them during runtime.

Comment: Aleks G was quite right about the whole answer. I dont see anything to downvote in his answer. Im accepting his answer as the correct solution for my question

Answer (score 0):

Each of the `get` family of methods on `ResultSet` has an overloaded variant that takes a column name as argument. You can use this instead to reduce reliance on ordering of columns.

```
ResultSet results = ...;
results.getString(1);
```

You could do this:

```
results.getString("name");
```

But the preferred way of handling this sort of problem is to impose an ordering of your own on the result set, by *explicitly* selecting the columns you want in the initial query.

Answer (score 0):

If your table adds a new column, then obviously you have to change your code, because in your code you use hardcoded value, I mean getString(1).

Instead use **ResultSetMetaData's getColumnCount** and do some other logic to get that many column values dynamically.

Another thing for your first question, **ResultSet** contains **getXXX()** methods with two types of parameters, **String column name** and **int column index**. You used the **index** instead of **column name** which will perform little faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to use `SELECT *`, instead you should select only the columns you are interested in. The reason is exactly what you mentioned: What happens if your DB changes. you don't want to go trhough the whole code and find and edit all `SELECT *` statements.

You don't need to put the result into your own map because you can already do:

```
result.getString("DETAILS_FILE");
```

But there are already other answers explaining that.

It would be further helpful to use a constant instead of the string "DETAILS_FILE". You can use the constant in the `SELECT` and in the `result.getString()`. In case your DB changes you only need to introduce a new constant or change an existing one.

Comment: agreed with u regarding usage of SELECT *. I will change it to the column names i require

Comment: While I agree regarding usage of SELECT *, there are valid reasons where this may be necessary.  There are also reasons why it may be necessary to read the data from a database and put it into your own map - for example, because you then pass this map to another layer of the app, where the database layer is not available.  On the whole, your answer, while correct in its own right, does not answer the question that the OP poses.