# result.getString("xxx") lot of times SLOW

Tags: java, resultset, getstring

I'm using a resultSet to transfer a table from one DB to the other.
But when getting the result from some rows it is too slow.
Here is the code:

```
    ResultSet result = stmt.getResultSet();
    while (result.next()) {
                result.getString("CPF");
                result.getString("TERMINAL");
                result.getString("XXXXX");
       ...................
            }
```

I get like 20 columns from this select, but sometimes the result.getString("") is really slow.
Do someone know why it could happen? or some way to improve the performance?

Comment: [might that help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941855/any-better-approach-rather-than-result-getstring-while-iterating-a-result-set)

Comment: @KevinEsche I'll try... and answer here in some time...

Comment: @KevinEsche didn't help... it is slow in a some rows in a specific result.getString(""), I'm trying to figure out why... =/